# Cannot read CSV file to array with Scanner

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am kinda new to this, but does anybody know why my code cannot read csv file? Here is my code:

```
try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/sdcard/test.txt"));
    // s.useDelimiter(";");

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
    s.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It does not matter if the file is .txt or .csv. It does not matter if I use delimiter or not. I do not get any error but I do not get any output either.

My .csv file looks like this:

```
010000;713150586024;fólie spodní 425;m
010001;9;folie vrch.Pečený bochník;m
010002;9;fólie černá sp.tvrdá 475;m
```

When I change the file to this it works:

```
010000;
010001;
010002;
```

So I guess the problem is whitespaces in between the words? Is there some solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by `it works`? After you read `.csv` file, how it looks like printed?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The output is exactly the same as it is written in .csv file.

010000;
010001;
010002;

It is in 3 lines. I am sorry I do not know how to write code in the comments.

Comment: And in the other case? You get an empty list? P.S.: For code, place your text between 2 of these ` chars.

Comment: Yes, for this case I get empty list 
`010000;713150586024;fólie spodní 425;m
010001;9;folie vrch.Pečený bochník;m
010002;9;fólie černá sp.tvrdá 475;m`

Comment: Just ran the code with the same csv and it worked with the `useDelimeter`.

Comment: How is the file encoded?  I reproduced your results if file encoded as UTF-8 but as ANSI  or UNICODE it produced results (which may lead to another issue where you mix `hasNextLine` and `next` - not sure if that is intended).

Comment: Adding `"utf-8"` on parameter to scanner ( `new Scanner(new File("..."),"utf-8")` seems to correct the issue (assuming the file is encoded as utf-8).

Comment: It was indeed problem with encoding. It was encoded in "windows-1250" so I just added it to: (new FileInputStream("/sdcard/test.csv"), "windows-1250"));

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to find any error with your code, for me it works. Probably there is any problem with the enconding of your csv file.

I suggest using a [`BufferedReader`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-buffered-reader) instead of a `Scanner` when reading files:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sdcard/test.txt"))) {
    String line;
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(";")));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also a [try with resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources) is usefull in this case so you don't have to explicitly call the method `close`.

If you want a more functional code you can use Java 8 Streams as following:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sdcard/test.txt"))) {
    br.lines()
            .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(";")))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can read more about Streams API [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams).

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with encoding. I just added this ', "windows-1250" ' to my code:

```
(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/test.csv"), "windows-1250"));
```

Thank you everybody :)